# How to open App Store instead of iTunes store with react-native-version-check

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, app-store

I am using react-native-version-check to open app store/play store if update is available, but on iOS it open iTunes store, I want to open AppStore.
This is my code:

```js
_onPressUpdate = async () => {
        Linking.openURL(await VersionCheck.getStoreUrl({ignoreErrors: false, appID: "407690035", appName: "hotel-tonight-last-minute", packageName: "com.hoteltonight.android.prod"}));
    }
    
    // this appID and appName is just from some random app on the app store for testing
```

Comment: Hm, according to [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/38296539) the iTunes store *is* the App Store for iOS

Comment: That link gives me 404. I think iTunes is available only in some countries.

Comment: You are right, it should have been https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3829653

Answer (score 0):

To open app store inside from react native app.
Go to google search your app on appstore copy that url

**Your app should be live on appstore to generate the link**

```
 const url = Platform.OS === 'android' ?
                    'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOUR_APP_ID'   :  'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/doorhub-driver/id_YOUR_APP_ID'
                Linking.openURL(url)
```